# Flash Audio Lag in Google Chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome, actionscript

I'm currently working on a flash game and, at least on my machine, the audio seems to lag by a fraction of a second in Chrome, but not in IE or FF. This isn't a huge deal, the game is still playable, but it's a little bit annoying. Is there anything I can do from a development standpoint to fix this issue or is it something the user would have to fix?

Edit: I've now tested it on two other machines and the same thing happened. The audio is delayed in chrome but not Firefox or IE.

Edit 2: I've also tried the same thing in a few popular games on Newgrounds to the same effect. Is this just something wrong with Chrome?

Edit 3: I tried lowering the bit rate of the audio from 44kHz to 22 and it didn't do anything to fix it. (It also sounded terrible, predictably)

Edit 4: To prove it's not a memory management problem I created a blank SWF that just plays an audio file on mouse click, it also has the lag issue. This is definitely not a Flash or AS3 isolated issue.

Comment: Given that this is a game, I would guess it has to do with poor memory management and resource allocation. I would recommend reading up on garbage collection: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=actionscript+garbage+collection

Comment: Why would this be browser specific though? I tried it on two other machines and they all showed the same thing. Delay in chrome, no delay in FireFox.

Comment: are you using Flash Player Debugger in Chrome ?

Comment: @Cyborg771 I know that Chrome uses a specific build of Flash Player, which could be the cause.

Comment: @João Mosmann I don't believe so. How would I check?

Comment: @Cyborg771 Right click on the flash object, and if the context menu has a "debug" (or "debugger", I forget) menu item, then you are running the debug build of Flash player.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that.

Comment: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html This will give you the particular version, you could use Mr. Doob's Stat component to get some info about the run-time framerate and CPU/Mem usage and see if there's a difference. https://github.com/mrdoob/Hi-ReS-Stats/

Comment: My guess would be some issue in the version of the flash player you're running in Chrome but I currently run quite a few browsers and haven't noticed this issue in Chrome while say watching video on youtube.  Chrome does automatically update it's version of flash player currently I'm running 11.3.31.222 if you could give me a site with a particular example I can let you know if I can replicate.

Comment: @shainusain I created a simple test here http://sdcinglis.com/Other/audioTest.html

All you have to do is click on the blue area and it should produce a sound effect. I'm not noticing this issue on youtube either, it only seems to exist with interactive audio playback.

Also, according to that link I'm using 11.3.31.222 (same as you)

Comment: If anyone can reduce this and file it as a ticket at new.crbug.com we might be able to see if we can address this from the Chrome side. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have/had the same problem with Chrome.

if you go to: chrome://plugins (->details) and disable PepperFlash, then it runs smooth. Not sure if Pepper is the default for Chrome, or if its the particular version of flash we installed.

C:\Users\ [USERNAME] \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\21.0.1180.75\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll

Comment: Pepper Flash seems to have become the default for Chrome ... ran into some issues with it on Windows 7 in the last few weeks.

Comment: On a side note: Pepperflash also messes up/doesnt register Mouse.Cursor settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had an intermittent audio and then the video started to lag. The solution was two fold:

1. Re-install chrome.
2. Get the latest Adobe Flash Player.

I had to do both things for it work properly. To get the plugins type the following in chrome address bar: chrome://plugins

After you install the latest player you need to disable the older one.

Hope this resolves your problem as it did for me.